# how to create multi site url to store particular information to particular site using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my Application, there is an option called "create site" that will create a new site URL. So the problem is I'm having so many collections and I need to show related data to the related site.

As an Admin I can create any number of sites and that will contain so many options like "Create User", "my account", "create project", "settings" and etc (In Navbar). So on selecting these options, it should fetch the data related to that option and that site...

For better understanding eg: In my application, Suppose if I create a new site URL something like `"www.mywebsite/new-website"` -- this URL is a new website it doesn't contain any data by default, all option like "create user, create project, etc.." that will be having data only if I add some data.

I will create another site URL like `"www.mywebsite/new-website1"` - initial no data will be present, after adding that will be having related information.

In MongoDB how do I achieve this using a single database? so I'm using MEAN stack application I need a solution on how to achieve this scenario, can someone help me to get a clear picture of MongoDB usage in this type of situation that will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The question really is way too broad, and put basically there is no **single** way or even **recommended** approach to doing this. Differing approaches are really about *"different needs"* for your particular application and the service you want to provide. You can either implement multiple database namespaces, or "prefix" collections or even just have a `"site"` identifier present on all necessary collections. You probably should instead do some research on ["multi tenant"](https://www.google.com/search?q=multi+tenant&oq=multi+tenant) architectures, than rely on a "short" answer here.

Comment: Also, take a look at things like [wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress) or [woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce) ( really just randomly hitting "W" on Github here ) and scour their source for the parts that interact with their supported database engines and the approaches used. Both of those have some sort of "multi tenant" concept, so there will be patterns in there you can learn from and implement your own things. But really a "how to" is basically a book, and not an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any example provided will be helpful for me, if not can you brief more about your answer or any other alternative way will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By using express routes, a simple way is to nest routers by attaching them as middleware on an other router.

In this way, you can have a collection for websites and use the websiteId as reference in all other collections.

**So the routes become:**

`GET /` -> `hello websites`

`GET /new-website` -> `Hello from Website : new-website`

`GET /new-website/users` -> `List users from website : new-website`

`GET /new-website/users/101` -> `Hello User : 101 from website : new-website`

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var siteRouter = express.Router();
// you need to set mergeParams: true on the router,
// if you want to access params from the parent router
var userRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

// you can nest routers by attaching them as middleware:
siteRouter.use("/:sitename/users", userRouter);

siteRouter.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send("hello websites");
});

siteRouter.route("/:sitename").get(function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send("Hello from Website : " + req.params.sitename);
});

userRouter.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send("List users from website " + req.params.sitename);
});

userRouter.route("/:userId").get(function(req, res) {
  res
    .status(200)
    .send(
      "Hello User : " + req.params.userId + " from website :" + req.params.sitename
    );
});

app.use("/", siteRouter);

app.listen(3000);
```

NOTE:- I had only added GET request, use POST request to create websites, users in the responsive routes and sufficient Authorisation has to be checked before giving access to routes.